# I tried to connect to xampp database but its failing

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying so hard to connect to the database but am failing, am using xampp with php 7.0.8, am confused i dont know how i should access my database.
Can someone help me please?

Here is my code:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
```

Comment: And "I am trying so hard" and "I am failing" means what _exactly_?

Comment: mysql is NOT supported in php 7 - use mysqli This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

Comment: thanks, arkascha it gave me a clue

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`. As mysql extension is now `deprecated`.
Following is the `syntax` for `mysqli`:

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);
```